# using mouseover to show search input type

Tags: jquery, toggle, show, mouseover

I'm trying to achieve a jquery function, by mouseoever a submit button, I want my search input type to appear, the same kind of effect as a slideToggle.

I don't want to use width toggle because I don't want my search input to hide when hovering again my submit button. This is why I use show();.

but the effect is not perfect, the bottom border moves. as shown on my 1st EXAMPLE on my JsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/76y7czvz/1/

what I'm trying to do is to have the same show function as in my 1st EXEMPLE, but with the same effect as shown on my 2nd EXEMPLE on my jsfiddle.

here is my Jquery Code :

```
$( "#searchsubmit" ).on( "mouseenter", function() {
$("#s").show("xslow");
});

$( "#searchsubmit_2" ).on( "mouseenter", function() {
$("#s_2").animate({width: 'toggle'}, "xslow");
});
```

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optionally use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to achieve this:

```
$( "#searchsubmit_2" ).one( "mouseenter", function() {
    $("#s_2").animate({width: 'toggle'}, "xslow");
});
```

This will prevent the input from toggling when it hovered over again.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/76y7czvz/4/)

Comment: thanks @M.Doye, that's exactly what I was looking for ! didn't know about the "one", perfect tricks

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to `<input type="search" id="s"` and then use the class as a flag. Each time, switch the class to keep in track of the state, something like;

```
$( "#searchsubmit" ).on( "mouseenter", function() {
    if ( $("#s").is( ".a" ) ) {
        $("#s").show("xslow").removeClass("a").addClass("b");
    }else{
        $("#s").hide("xslow").removeClass("b").addClass("a");
    }
});
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/76y7czvz/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @blasteralfred Ψ, but that's not what I was looking for, thanks anyway